# more than one library with package name 'com.shopify.buy'

Tags: android, shopify

I am creating the android application with e-commerce by using the `Shopify API`. I have followed the [link](https://help.shopify.com/api/sdks/mobile-buy-sdk/android/integration-guide/setup)

I am getting the

> " Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. >  more than one library with package name 'com.shopify.buy' ".

Here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.kotesh.shopifynewandroid"
            minSdkVersion 23
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile ('com.shopify.mobilebuysdk:buy:2.1.0') {
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-wallet'
        }
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile project(':buy-2.1.0')
    }
```

I am unable to find the solution for the error and i searched for it, please any one can help me, thanks in advance. Post the comment if you want to down vote.

Comment: Can you show build.gradle of buy-2.1.0 project that you are trying to compile?

Comment: I have created with Sample application with MainActivity.java and activity_main.xml file and others and shown the build.gradle file entirely .

Comment: then what you're trying to compile? seems you have at least two modules

Comment: I have two modules as per "Shopify" API says. I have added buy-2.1.0 to my sample application.

Comment: You can't have one build.gradle for two module. check this but-2.1.0 module and look at its build.gradle file

Comment: ok got it thank you.